# Постановка ударения в html

Tags: html, шрифты

Пытаюсь поставить ударение над заглавной буквой "У" в шрифте Open Sans Condensed, но при его постановке шрифт буквы У меняется на другой.
Я не могу понять: по сути знак ударения отдельный символ, почему он меняет шрифт буквы, над которой он ставится?

Сделал с помощью

```
<span style="position:relative;margin-left:-13px;margin-right:3px"> ́</span>
```

Выглядит неплохо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот тут все есть - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Все, что там есть перепробовал. Вы вопрос прочитайте.
Ударение ставится, но оно меняет шрифт буквы, над которой стоит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняет он шрифт на другой, потому что шрифт который вы подключаете не содержит символов с ударениями, а у стандартных шрифтов данные комбинации есть.

Решение: Найдите расширенную версию своего шрифта с ударениями.

Comment: Т.е. в шрифте должна быть буква с ударением, а поставить ее можем либо вставив ее, либо вставив букву и знак ударения?
Нужная мне буква У с ударением отсутствует. Получается выхода нет?)

Comment: @user2849166 Если не найдете расширенный шрифт с ударениями, то да, хорошего решения не будет. Ну либо вы можете подогнать ударение через `position:relative`, но это уже не красивое решение)

Comment: Спасибо, сделал так..

Comment: @user2849166 Выглядит хорошо)